# HTTP GET vs POST for Idempotent Reporting

Tags: ajax, forms, http, post, get

I'm building a web-based reporting tool that queries **but does not change** large amounts of data.

In order to verify the reporting query, I am using a form for input validation.

I know the following about HTTP GET:

1. It should be used for idempotent requests
2. Repeated requests may be cached by the browser

**What about the following situations?**

1. The data being reported changes every minute and *must not be cached*?
2. The query string is *very large* and greater than the 2000 character URL limit?

I know I can easily just use POST and "break the rules", but **are there definitive situations in which POST is recommended for idempotent requests**?

Also, I'm submitting the form via AJAX and the framework is Python/Django, but I don't think that should change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using POST for this sort situation is acceptable. Citing the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a
> resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200
> (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status,
> depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that
> describes the result.

In your case a "search result" resource is created on the server which adheres to the HTTP POST request specification. You can either opt to return the result resource as the response or as a separate URI to the just created resource and may be deleted as the result resource is no longer necessary after one minute's time(i.e as you said data changes every one minute).

`The data being reported changes every minute`

Every time you make a request, it is going to create a new resource based on your above statement.

Additionally you can return `201` status and a URL to retrieve the search result resource but I m not sure if you want this sort of behavior but I just provided as a side note.

Second part of your first question says results must not be cached. Well this is something you configure on the server to return necessary HTTP headers to force intermediary proxies and clients to not cache the result, for example, with `If-Modified-Since`, `Cache-control` etc.

Your second question is already answered as you have to use POST request instead of GET request due to the URL character limit.